# Create string for report from bit fields in Access 2013

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm building an access database to track airborne operations in an army unit. One of the requirements is that I be able to output the stored data onto an army form.

This form has a label in which I need to enter the type of operation, which can be one or a combination of the following:

Administrative, Tactical, Mass Tactical, Combat, Night, Combat Equipment.

Based on that, I store the data as check boxes, which feed yes/no (not triple state) fields in the actual database.

What I want to do is be able to print (in a report) the actual accepted abbreviation (i.e. A/NT, T, MT, C, N, CE). To do this, I've tried

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
Dim strJumpType As String
strJumpType = ""

If Me.chkAdminNonTactical = True Then
    strJumpType = strJumpType & "A/NT/"
End If
If Me.chkTactical = True Then
    strJumpType = strJumpType & "T/"
End If
If Me.chkMassTactical = True Then
    strJumpType = strJumpType & "MT/"
End If
If Me.chkCombat = True Then
    strJumpType = strJumpType & "C/"
End If
If Me.chkNight = True Then
    strJumpType = strJumpType & "N/"
End If
If Me.chkCombatEquipment = True Then
    strJumpType = strJumpType & "CE/"
End If

If Right(strJumpType, 1) = "/" Then

    strJumpType = Left(strJumpType, Len(strJumpType) - 1)

End If

MsgBox strJumpType, vbOKOnly ' test string

Me.lblJumpType.Caption = strJumpType

End Sub
```

While this works, it requires me to add invisible checkboxes to the form. I'd like to access the current record directly, but each method I've tried (me.XXX or currentrecord.XXX or setting a variable that refers to the current recordset) fails.

So my question is, is this really the best method, or is there a more elegant / efficient way to do this? Right now I only have about 500 people doing ~6 jumps per year, so there isn't a noticeable hit to performance. I suspect that if I have a larger dataset, this will start to become a bottleneck.

Also, I'd like to improve my overall programming skills. This will be run on Access 2013 or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure seems fine to me. You have six categories, and any combination of them can be selected. On your form accepting input for a jump, you either need six check boxes or a single listbox that lets you select multiple items. This solution starts after you have taken the input and stored it in a record. I am assuming your data looks something like:

```
 JumpID|ANT|T|MT|C|N|CE
 1     |T  |F|T |F|F|T
```

Your report would pull each record and use a single text box control to put together the items. Then you would have the control source for the box be this:

```
=Switch([ANT]=0,"A/NT/") & Switch([T]=0,"T/") & Switch([MT]=0,"MT/") & 
 Switch([C]=0,"C/") & Switch([N]=0,"N/") & Switch([CE]=0,"CE/")
```

That would leave you with "A/NT/T/MT/C/N/CE/" as a result if all are selected. To take the last slash off, you just have to wrap it with a LEFT statement like you did in VBA:

```
=Left(Switch([ANT]=0,"A/NT/") & Switch([T]=0,"T/") & Switch([MT]=0,"MT/") & 
 Switch([C]=0,"C/") & Switch([N]=0,"N/") & Switch([CE]=0,"CE/"),
 Len(Switch([ANT]=0,"A/NT/") & Switch([T]=0,"T/") & Switch([MT]=0,"MT/") & 
 Switch([C]=0,"C/") & Switch([N]=0,"N/") & Switch([CE]=0,"CE/"))-1)
```

This ends up looking ugly, but you only have to enter it once, and the beauty of it is it will get your consolidated jump type into a single textbox without ever having to touch VBA. That should make your reports easier to work with and design.

On a side note, Access is pretty great at creating government forms based on the templates. It can really simplify your life!

Comment: Thanks for the code - I hadn't seen the Switch function before, so that's awesome to see how it works. It turns out that I needed to change the 0's to -1's to get the right formula, but other than that, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is not that bad. It really depends on the situation. The recordset for reports are often unavailable. Invisible fields have a small performance impact as far as I know.

If it's a report based on a query, you might want to create the string using a user-defined function or just plane SQL in the query.
If it's a report based on a table, you could add a calculated field to the table if this is information you want to access often.

You might want to move the calculation out of VBA and into the control source of a text control. The expression would be something like this:

```
=IIF(chkAdminNonTactical; "A/NT/"; "") & IIF( chkTactical; "T/"; "") & IIF( .... etc
```

I would probably advise you to use that last option, because it probably would improve performance and avoiding vba if possible is good imho.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code solution for anyone else who needs to do something like this. It's based 99.9% on Sandpiper's suggestion. No more hidden checkboxes, and no requirement to run VBA to get the correct output in the form.

```
=Left(Switch([AdminNonTactical]=-1,"A/NT/") & Switch([Tactical]=-1,"T/") &
Switch([MassTactical]=-1,"MT/") & Switch([Combat]=-1,"C/") & 
Switch([Night]=-1,"N/") & Switch([CombatEquipment]=-1,"CE/") & 
Switch([Jumpmaster]=-1,"J/") & Switch([AssistantJumpmaster]=-1,"AJ/") & 
Switch([Safety]=-1,"Safety/") & 
Switch([DZSO]=-1,"DZSO/"),Len(Switch([AdminNonTactical]=-1,"A/NT/") & 
Switch([Tactical]=-1,"T/") & Switch([MassTactical]=-1,"MT/") & 
Switch([Combat]=-1,"C/") & Switch([Night]=-1,"N/") & 
Switch([CombatEquipment]=-1,"CE/") & Switch([Jumpmaster]=-1,"J/") & 
Switch([AssistantJumpmaster]=-1,"AJ/") & Switch([Safety]=-1,"Safety/") & 
Switch([DZSO]=-1,"DZSO/"))-1)
```